# Error in using string resources in IntentService

Tags: android, android-resources, intentservice

I am trying to get string resource value from IntentService as follows :

```
String errorTitle = getResources().getString(R.string.no_Internet_connection_error_title);
```

But it shows an error `no_Internet_connection_error_title cannot be resolved or is not a field`.

When I type `R.string.`, eclipse shows a list of android defined strings, not defined by me.

I use string resource in activity, but not able to use in IntentService.

Comment: import your R class `import com.example.androidtest.R;`

Comment: please remove R.String impost and import your R.class file

Comment: probably it is a wrong import. You can use prefix (package name) before to ensure you are using the right package. Does it work if you use ?
`getResources().getString(yourproject.package.name.R.string.no_Internet_connection_error_title)`

Comment: Have you tried cleaning your project

Comment: Importing package name worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thought one of the guys who commented will post an answer. But as they have not I am posting it.

The solution was either to import `R.java` file using package name :

```
import com.android.myApp.R;
```

Or to use whole package name to get string :

```
getResources().getString(com.android.myApp.R.string.no_Internet_connection_error_title);
```